# Flutter (Dart) Optional Parameters with Default Values with the data type Function?

Tags: flutter, dart, optional-parameters

so I am trying to create a custom widget for my project, and some instances of the class will require a onFinish function. However I cannot seem to set a default value for the function data type, it keeps saying: "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant."

Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? Thanks

This is my code so you can see what i am on about:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    super.key,
    this.title = "",
    this.message = "",
    this.actions = const [],
    this.onFinished = () {},
  });

  final String title;
  final String message;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final Function onFinished;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Taking Function as required parameter, you can make it nullable and since most of the onClick callbacks accepts nullable function, it will be easy for you to handle.

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({
    super.key,
    this.title = "",
    this.message = "",
    this.actions = const [],
    this.onFinished,
  });

  final String title;
  final String message;
  final List<Widget> actions;
  final Function? onFinished;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(onTap: onFinished, child: Container());
  }
}
```

or if you want to use onFinished Function as a callback function then you can use it like this. `onFinished?.call()`

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way of adding a constant value to a function in dart. I thought this might have been the case, and I would need to allow the value to be null if nothing has been passed into to parameter. Thanks for your help and quick response.

Comment: @RishV Anonymous functions can never be compile-time constants; they are created at runtime.  If you want a function as a constant value, make it a global or `static` named function.